# A theorem about angles in the form of arctan(1/n)

Tags: mathematics, geometry, number-theory

There is a famous classical geometry puzzle about the angles formed by integer coordinates:

> What is the sum of angle A and B in the following image? Do not use any advanced mathematics such as trigonometric formulas or complex numbers.
>
> [image]

with an elegant answer using pure geometry (spoiler-ed for those who want to try out themselves):

> [image]

Now, we consider a general problem involving angles in the form of arctan(1/n), which is the smallest angle formed by a right triangle of height 1 and width n (an integer). For example, the angle A in the above image is equal to arctan(1/3), and B is arctan(1/2).

Prove or disprove the following statement:

> Given two angles α=arctan(1/n) and β=arctan(1/m) where n and m are integers, it is possible to draw three triangles ABC, DEF, and GHI on a Cartesian plane, such that all vertices have integer coordinates and the following conditions are satisfied for each triangle:
>
> - the edge AB is parallel to the x-axis, angle A = α, angle B = β
> - the edge DE is parallel to the x-axis, angle E = α, angle F = β
> - the edge GH is parallel to the x-axis, angle I = α, angle G = β

Comment: FWIW, [here](https://gist.github.com/PM2Ring/0ed5c995f59a50529964d50fec93049b#file-acot_triangle-svg) is an SVG of an alternative demonstration of the fact in your spoiler. And if you like this kind of thing, here's a huge collection of integer (and some half integer) [arccot identities](http://www.machination.eclipse.co.uk/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The statement is

> true

Proof:

> The  triangle can be simply constructed by joining two right-angled triangles of height 1 together, leading to the points =(0, 0), =(+, 0), =(, 1).
>
>  Note that once you have the right-angled triangle  with =(0, 0), =(, 0), =(, 1), then you can simply extend the side  by a factor (+)/ to get point  of the triangle  that we want.
>
>  So let's construct a triangle similar to  such that its hypotenuse is horizontal. We can do this by scaling it by a factor : (0, 0) (<sup>2</sup>, 0) (<sup>2</sup>, ), which allows us to join a rotated similar unscaled triangle (<sup>2</sup>, 0) (<sup>2</sup>, ) (<sup>2</sup>+1, 0). This results in the triangle  with =(0, 0), =(<sup>2</sup>+1, 0), =(<sup>2</sup>, ) where the top vertex  is the right angle.  We can now extend the side  by a factor (+)/ to find point . This gives the triangle  we want: =(0, 0), =(<sup>2</sup>+1, 0), =((+), +).
>
>  [image]
>
>  The  triangle is the same as  but with  and  swapped.

Comment: Jaap claiming the opposite...this can't be good.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis You seem to have focused on one particular example which does not work in your answer but discounted many examples that might work.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it is the first fully correct one. My approach was to apply the scaling and work with the product of two-square sums to find the coordinates of the point F, which gives the same coordinates as this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is

> true

Because

> Here is a constructive proof.
>
>  I am using the fact that in the space of Gaussian
>  integers (complex integers) multiplication represents an angle-preserving transformation.
>
>  Triangle ABC can be created easily by setting A=(0,0), B=(n+m,0), C=(n,1).
>
>  To find triangle DEF, consider CAB in the complex plane and multiply it by -n+i.
>  DE ends up aligned with x or the real axis by construction.
>  Likewise, to find triangle GHI, multiply BCA by -m-i.
>
>  As an example, n=2, m=3.
>
>  A = (0,0), B=(5,0), C=(2,1)
>
>  D: $C(2-i) = (2+i)(-2+i) = -5$.
>  E: $A(2-i) = 0$.
>  F: $B(2-i) = 5(-2+i) = -10+5i$.
>
>  This gives  D = (-5,0),   E = (0,0), F = (-10,5).
>
>  G: $B(-3-i) = 5(-3-i) = -15 -5i$.
>  H: $C(-3-i) = (2+i)(-3-i) = -5 + -5i$.
>  I: $A(-3-i) = 0$.
>
>  Giving G = (-15,-5),  H = (-5,-5),  I = (0,0),
>
>  Triangle ABC obviously has the required angles α at A and β at B.
>  The other triangles are just ABC rotated and scaled, preserving the angles.
>  So it is easy to see that A, E and I all have the same angle, α,
>  and B, F, G have the same angle, β.

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, the statement is true.

Proof:

> Let the unnamed angle in the three triangles be $180°-\phi$.
>  That is, $$\phi=\alpha+\beta$$ Thus, $$\tan\phi=\frac{n+m}{nm-1}$$
>
>  The $ABC$ case is obvious. We have $AB$ of length $n+m$, and the perpendicular height of the triangle is 1.
>  Eg, $$A=(-n,0), B=(m,0), C=(1,0)$$
>  The other two cases are symmetrical to each other, so I'll just illustrate the case with $\alpha$ on the $X$ axis:
>  [image: arccot triangle]
>  $$tan\alpha=\frac{n+m}{nm+n^2}=\frac1n$$
>  For the other case, simply swap $\alpha$ & $\beta$, and $n$ & $m$.